# why isn't my 'find -exec du' working?

Tags: find, disk-usage

I want to get the disk usage of a directory tree, excluding branches that begin with '.', and I will eventually want to run this over ssh, so I prefer to not use a pipe.  When I run the following, I get a list of all the directories:

```
> /bin/find . \( -name .[^.]\* -prune \) -o \( -type d -exec /bin/echo -sh {} + \)
-sh ./dir-1 ./dir-2 ./dir-3 [...]
```

When I run du by itself, I get the expected output:

```
> /bin/du -sh ./dir-1 ./dir-2 ./dir3 [...]
11M     ./dir-1
254K    ./dir-2
15M     ./dir-3
[...]
```

When I combine the two, I only get the total line:

```
> /bin/find . \( -name .[^.]\* -prune \) -o \( -type d -exec /bin/du -sh {} + \)
1.4G    .
```

BTW, I'm running Oracle Linux Server release 7.9 and GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Did you read the `du` manual to see what the `-s` option does?  You probably want `\;` at the end instead of `+`.

Comment: What do you want excluded, the display of certain subtrees or the size counting of certain subtrees?

Comment: @they Yes, and on my system the manual says that '''-s''' will "display only a total for each argument" which is exactly what I want.  However, a bit more testing reveals that if the arguments include both a parent and its child directories, only the parent's utilization is displayed.  I guess I need to file a bug report and rethink my approach.

Comment: @sudodus I want to rearrange some file systems across multiple devices and want to decide if ./dir-X can be moved and replaced with a symlink.  To that end, I don't want to see totals for, e.g. '''./dir-X/.git''' or '''./dir-X/.cache'' but do want them included in the total for '''./dir-X'''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When summarising, `du` only counts directories once — so

```
du -sh . somedir
```

will only show `.`, because `somedir` is accounted for in `.`. Order is significant, so

```
du -sh somedir .
```

will show both `somedir` and `.`, and won’t count `somedir` in `.`.

Your `find` command ends up including `.`, so that’s all you see, since it appears first. You can avoid that by specifying a minimum depth; then you’ll see the totals for all the directories directly under the current directory.

If that’s all you want, then

```
du -sh */
```

will produce the same result, without using `find`.

If you want detailed, per-directory output, you need to tell `find` to list directories depth-first; `-prune` doesn’t work then, but filtering on paths does:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d \! -path '*/.*' -exec du -sh {} +
```

(Note that hidden directories’ sizes will still be accounted for in any non-hidden parent directory’s size.)

If your `du` supports `--exclude`, you can use that to achieve the same effect:

```
du -h --exclude '*/.*' ./
```